# Visual studio cannot start debugging because the debug target is missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I have this code but it has an error. Im using c# and sql server.

```
          barcodeScanner = BarcodeScannerFacade.GetBarcodeScanner();
          barcodeScanner.BarcodeScan += new
          BarcodeScanner.BarcodeScanEventHandler(barcodeScanner_BarcodeScan);
```

Comment: did u check stack trace..

Comment: Check [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1a89d2df-0c57-4bb2-8c1a-b619e6cbb065/cannot-start-debugging-because-the-debug-target-is-missing). In short this says "In this, Go to build, and then check the "Output" section at the bottom End

Browse for correct Directory Path. "Default is Bin\debug" you may want to change it where the actual exe / dll is.

this has solved my problem as my Build environment was keeping the Target Exe Somewhere else and the code somewhere else.."

Comment: I already change the directory path to c:\Users\ASUS\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsForms2 but the same error occur.

Comment: I solved it but it I have another problem. The code has blue underline on it. Can someone tell me why?

Comment: Is it getting compiled? 
A red underline identifies a syntax error, such as a missing semicolon or mismatched braces, or a semantic error.
A green underline identifies a potential compiler warning. 
A Blue identifies compiler errors.